# Convergence of an integral with one singularity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does the following integral converge?

$$\int_c^1\frac{1}{bx\left(1-x+\frac{1}{b}\log(x)\right)}dx$$ where $b>1$ and $c\in (0,1)$?

I would like to prove that at least for some $c$ close to $1$ that integral converge.

The denominator is equal to $0$ in two points: $\bar c$ and $1$.

I can avoid the singularity in $\bar c$ by taking $c>\bar c$, but what about the singularity in $1$?

Could I prove that this integral converges?

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have: $0<1-x+\frac{1}{b}\log(x) \leq 1-x$ for $x<1$ and $x$ close to $1$. So:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{bx(1-x+\frac{1}{b}\log(x))} > \frac{1}{bx(1-x)}
\end{align} 
What do you know about the integral of the  expression in the RHS? Conclude.

Comment: it diverges. Thank you a lot